# Need to reduce the server request and response time

Tags: node.js, performance, express, loading, pagespeed

I have a MERN based website which uses Express.js to start an https server. The website was working fine some time back but now it is taking a lot of time to interact with the backend.

To find out the reason, I did some debugging and found out that the backend server returns response very quickly but the request reaches to it in a very long time. Here is an example of a test url: https://www.edvicer.com:1235/test. We are doing a lot of changes at the moment so please bear with me if the above url is down at a certain time due to some testing going on in our end. Please try 10 minutes later and it will work fine. On opening it, you will see that the page takes a lot of time to open even though it has a very simple code:

```
app.get("/test",function(req,res){
  console.log("reached test request");
  res.send("Hello")
})
```

When opening https://www.edvicer.com:1235/test, it takes a lot of time to print "reached test request" on console but no time to load the page after the print statement.

Please let me know the solution to increase the speed of the loading or which direction to think in. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is in the time to open the connection. Once it's open, the request and response are very quick.

Comment: Where are you hosting this? Either your app "goes to sleep" , dont get cpu, or some dns or firewall issue, most likely.

Comment: @Brandon yes, exactly. If you know how the opening of the connection can be sped up, please let me know.

Comment: @RaniSharim, the website is hosted on Bluehost, I don't think the problem is with the cpu or any firewall issue. Port 1235 in the mentioned example is for one backend server. If you see the main website, www.edvicer.com, the time to first bite is very less and the connection is established very quickly.

Comment: I suggest contacting Bluehost.

Comment: @Brandon I tried but they only provide assist in the websites created using Wordpress or any of the pre-installed softwares on Bluehost. They say that they can't help when the website is created from scratch using Node.js